# Multiple $and $or in a MongoDb find

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a query I can't figure out. That query returns nothing:

```
 const read = await db.collection("action_traces")
    .find(
      { $and: [
        { $or:
          [
            {"receipt.receiver": "newdexpocket"},
            {"act.account": "newdexpocket"}
          ]
        },
        { $and:
          [
            {"block_time":{ "$gte": "2018-10-02T00:00:00.000Z" } },
            {"block_time":{ "$lt": "2018-10-03T00:00:00.000Z" } }
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
```

Whereas the following request returns part of the results I want:

```
 const read = await db.collection("action_traces")
    .find(
    { $and: [
      { $or:
        [
          {"receipt.receiver": "newdexpocket"},
          {"act.account": "newdexpocket"}
        ]
      },
      {"block_time":{ "$lt": 2018-10-03T00:00:00.000Z } }
    ]
  })
```

The issue is simple, how can get rid of the documents that are older than `2018-10-02T00:00:00.000Z`? What am I doing wrong in my first request?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `and` between the critieria should be implied, the below query should be equivalent to what you're trying to achieve (if I understood it right). Please test it.

```
db.collection("action_traces")
.find({ $or:[
        {"receipt.receiver": "newdexpocket"},
        {"act.account": "newdexpocket"}
      ],
     "block_time":{ "$gte": "2018-10-02T00:00:00.000Z" ,"$lt": "2018-10-03T00:00:00.000Z" } 
})
```

Comment: Thanks, at least you're query is running but it seems to be running almost endlessly. When I look at the logs it's not really endless but as the collection is super big (700gb) it seems like it's parsing the whole collection so maybe it's only considering the `$gte` part of the query?

Comment: Just for information, I've also printed out the query in the console to make sure this isn't a formatting issue but the strings are correct. The first query ( when it's just `$lt`) runs in roughly 10 seconds, whereas the query with both `$gte` and `$lt` is still running after multiple minutes (I'm killing it manually each time). Any idea?

Comment: It's actually working, I inputted a couple extra `{ }` so that wasn't working properly but now it is ;-) Problem solved then, thanks for the answer :p